# Can you identify this (possibly Bulgarian) uniform?

Tags: world-war-one, identification, austria-hungary, bulgaria

can someone identify the country the uniform is from?

[image]

Context:
Must have been born before 1880. First served in the Austro-Hungarian army, perhaps as an officer servant, possibly to a man who later became Ferdinand I. of Bulgaria. And he likely followed him to Bulgaria, where he seems to have made a career.
Decorations I think I identified: German Iron Cross, Bulgarian Order of Military Merit.

My working assumption it's a Bulgarian uniform from a later stage of WW1. Perhaps even after the war.

Thank you.

Comment: When was this photograph made?

Comment: I don't have the date. With 99% probability it's one of a few photographs taken in Sofia, Bulgaria.

Comment: Is it a color photograph, or was it recolorized?

Comment: The photograph was recolorized via MyHeritage.com